# How can I implement useEffect after page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm writing my first project on React and I'm stuck with this problem.

I have an authorization form. And the method which checks if user is authorized inside useEffect. Whether the user is authorized or not is set to **isAuth** field.
Here is the method:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from "../http";
import ResetService from "../services/ResetService";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Store {
    user = {} as IUser;
    isAuth = false;
    isLoading = false;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    setAuth(bool: boolean) {
        this.isAuth = bool;
    }

    setUser(user: IUser) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    setLoading(bool: boolean) {
        this.isLoading = bool;
    }

    async login(email: string, password: string) {
        try {

            const response = await AuthService.login(email, password);
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
            this.setAuth(true);
            this.setUser(response.data.user);
            
        } catch (e: any) {}
    }

    async checkAuth() {
        this.setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<AuthResponse>(`${API_URL}/refresh`, {withCredentials: true});
            
            
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
            this.setAuth(true);
            this.setUser(response.data.user);
           
        } catch (e: any) {} finally {
            this.setLoading(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is useEffect in my app.js file:

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Context } from './index';
import RegistrationForm from './components/RegistrationForm';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import Home from './components/Home';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProfilePage from './components/ProfilePage';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

const App = () => {

  const {store} = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      store.checkAuth();
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path={'/'} element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path={'/registration'} element={<RegistrationForm />}/>
        <Route path={'/login'} element={<LoginForm  />} />
        <Route path={'/profile'} element={<ProfilePage  />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default observer(App);
```

I have another page "/profile" in my ProfilePage component and if user is not authorized it redirects to main page:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Context } from '../index';
import FileUpload from './FileUpload';

const ProfilePage = () => {

    const {store} = useContext(Context);
    console.log(store.isAuth); //false

    if (!store.isAuth) {
        return (
        <Navigate to="/"/>
        )
        
    }
    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <div className='mb-10'>Email: {store.user.email}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default observer(ProfilePage);
```

But if I refresh the page **isAuth** returns false and redirects even the user is authorized. On the main page it seems to work, but it returns firstly false and only then true, I don't know if it's correct. I'd appreciate any response about my code, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Store {
    user = {} as IUser;
    isAuth = false;
    isLoading = false;
```

This is the key part here. On first render after refresh, isAuth is `false`. You then call `store.checkAuth();`, which is an async operation and can take many seconds to resolve.

You need to figure out a way to know the authentication status instantly after refreshing. IE keeping a value in the stoarge that indicates session timeout

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response [Leland Barton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392087/leland-barton)

In accordance with your answer, I added the following to my code:

After login I save "isAuth" status to local storage with the string value of "true", and setting my isAuth field in my store accordingly this localstorage value. I'm new in React and if you tell me if it's ok to do it this way , I would really appreciate that :)

My code:

```
imports ...

export default class Store {
    ...
    isAuth = localStorage.getItem('isAuth') === 'true' ? true : false;
    ...

    async login(email: string, password: string) {
        try {
            ...
            localStorage.setItem('isAuth', "true");    
            ...
            
        } catch (e: any) {}
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong here, I can't store all that I need in localstorage, probably I should rewrite my code structure